# Extremely Long Boot Time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi, touchpad

I installed **11.10** via **Wubi** on my **Toshiba NB-205 netbook (Intel Atom N280 / 1.66 GHz, 1GB RAM, Mobile Intel 945GSE Express)**. After the initial boot and login, which went fine, I was checking out the desktop when **the cursor froze**. I could navigate with the keyboard but it appeared that the **touchpad** was **not working**. I restarted the netbook and after grub was chain-loaded and Ubuntu was selected, booting appeared to **hang on** a **blank purple screen**. After about five minutes lightDM appeared and I could login normally; also the touchpad was working normally. I checked to see if there was a driver that needed to be installed in case the touchpad was causing boot issues but **no proprietary drivers** are found via Additional Drivers. After reading similar problems, with no working solutions, it seemed it was a good idea to see if **dmesg** held any clues. Admittedly, I am not sure what to look for. I did notice the following lines:

`[     0.263568]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND), returned control mask: 0x1d`

`[ 0.263575]  ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM`

I do not know if that is normal. Additionally, this popped up a few times:

`EXT4-fs (loop0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount.ro`

Basically, I just searched for "fail" and "error" in a text editor and those are what were found. Does anyone have any clue what may be causing the long boot time?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Install `bootchart`. Then after your next boot look in `/var/log/bootchart` for a nice picture of your boot. You can probably find out what's taking so long from that.

Answer (score 1):

Checking [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks/ToshibaNB205) it indicates you should use the [kernel boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) `nohz=off`. It's also described in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/linux/+bug/577660). Since the bug indicates the problem is in the bios, you could try updating the bios and see whether Toshiba have fixed it.

Comment: Yes that seemed to do the trick. I was unaware of that page and whether or not it still applied. Thank you.